# How many $T_0$ Spaces for $\vert T \vert =4$ ? ($X = \{1,2,3\}$)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

As literally I said in the title, the question require the number of the $T_0$ spaces for the topology $(X,T)$ [Condition : $X = \{1,2,3\}$ with $\vert T \vert =4$]

There are just two cases for the  $\vert T \vert =4$ like the form either $\{\{a\}, \{b,c\}, X, \phi\}$ or $\{\{a\}, \{a,c\}, X, \phi\}$.

For the first case $\{\{a\}, \{b,c\}, X, \phi\}$ is not $T_0$. Because considering the any open sets of the $b$, $O_b$ includes the $c$

For the second case, $\{\{a\}, \{a,c\}, X, \phi\}$ is not $T_0$. Because considering the any open sets of the $c$, $O_c$ includes the $a$

So my conclusion is there aren't any $T_0$ spaces. So the number of that is $0$

But the answer was $6$. It claimed  $\{\{a\}, \{a,c\}, X, \phi\}$ is $T_0$ spaces. I can't understand why the answer should that be. Is my answer is right? I bet the my things are right.

Comment: Why not $\{\{a\}, \{b\}, X, \emptyset\}$ as another possible form? Or $\{\{a, b\}, \{b, c\}, X, \emptyset\}$?

Comment: Because $\{a,b\}$(union) can be open set for your first case. Then,  $\vert T \vert =5 $. For your second case $\{b\}$(intersection) can be open. so  $\vert T \vert =5 $

Comment: Oops! That's big ol' brain fart from me. I'm too tired to be doing this. I'll keep my comment, in case anyone else makes the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning that $O_c$ contains $a$, in the contentious case, is a valid concern when testing if the space is $T_1$. Remember, to prove $(X, T)$ is $T_0$, for any $x, y \in X$, you need to produce $O_x, O_y \in T$ with $x \in O_x$ and $y \in O_y$, so that **either** $x \notin O_y$ **or** $y \notin O_x$.

In the case of $a$ and $c$, one can choose $a \in \{a\}$ and $c \in \{a, c\}$, and we have $c \notin \{a\}$, *and this is enough*. The fact that $a \in \{a, c\}$ is immaterial.

Comment: Note that on a finite set, there is only one $T_1$ topology. A $T_0$ topology is precisely a poset, so we're counting the posets here of a special type. Here the linear orders as $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}, X,\emptyset\}$ is just the poset $c \le b \le a$ and $3!=6$ hence the answer.

Comment: There are only three pairs to check $T_0$ for (as $\binom{3}{2}=3$) and the ones containing $a$ are made true by $\{a\}$ and the only other one is $b,c$ made true by $\{a,b\}$. So the topology with non-trivial open sets $\{a\},\{a,b\}$ is $T_0$. The other configurations are ruled out by the size of the topology.